# AWS CloudFormation cannot create a db.t2.micro instance in the specified AvailabilityZone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

I have a Database and a DBSecurityGroup inside a subnet and a VPC. but whenever I try to launch the stack, I get this error:

```
Database    CREATE_FAILED   Resource handler returned message: "Cannot create a db.t2.micro database instance because no subnets exist in availability zones with sufficient capacity for VPC and storage type : gp2 for db.t2.micro. Please first create at least one new subnet; choose from these availability zones: sa-east-1a, sa-east-1c, sa-east-1b. (Service: Rds, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 6b6ed3c0-6a29-4a2b-8f3b-6e278fc0e70e)" (RequestToken: 119fb2ad-f081-24e1-651f-c316f30ac4d3, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

I tried in all three available AvailabilityZones in South America, every single one returned the same error.
Here it is my Database, the DBSecurityGroup and the Subnet where he belongs to:

```
Database:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !GetAtt 
        - Subnet2
        - AvailabilityZone
      DBSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref DBSecurityGroup
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBStorage
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      Engine: !Ref Engine
      MasterUsername: !Ref MasterUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref MasterUserPassword
Subnet2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: sa-east-1b
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: grupo de seguranca do banco
      DBSecurityGroupIngress:
        - CIDRIP: 10.0.1.0/24
```

Will I have to set the Database to a region where he can instance a db.t2.micro?

Comment: Older instance types like T2 wind up deprecated over time, and AWS slowly lets the servers that host them die out as utilized capacity goes down. Is there a reason you can't just use T3? It'll be more performant for the same price.

Comment: @ceejayoz Isn't t3 out of free tier?

Comment: No. https://aws.amazon.com/free/ states "750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region".

Comment: @ceejayoz still getting the error with the t3.micro :(

Comment: You may need to bump from `gp2` to `gp3`, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not all instance types are available in every region. Try a different instance type. t3.micro would be the obvious choice. If that doesn't work try a few different instance types, even if you don't want to keep that instance type it would be useful information to help with your diagnosis.

I've also found that one availability zone in a region may not have instances available, but the other two do. You could try changing the AZ selected.

Newer regions don't have older instances. I guess older instances are probably removed at some point as well. There are so many instance types and sizes now it must be difficult to work out what the demand will be in each region. Specialty and older types are more likely to be unavialble.